# Detect on which entry / entries an asset is inserted

Tags: assets, assets-field

Is it possible to display in the asset overview on which entry / entries an asset is used? So that when I go into an asset, I have an overview of the entries where that asset is inserted.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing native that would add a column like that, so you'd need to create a plugin or [custom module](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/module-guide.html) that registers a custom column by listening to the `Asset::EVENT_REGISTER_TABLE_ATTRIBUTES` event, and rendering the content for that column (i.e. the list of related entries) via the `Asset::EVENT_SET_TABLE_ATTRIBUTE_HTML` event.

For that latter part, you'd need to create a query that queries for all entries related to each asset (the asset will be available via the `sender` attribute for the `SetElementTableAttributeHtmlEvent` instance passed to your `EVENT_SET_TABLE_ATTRIBUTE_HTML` event listener); rendering a list of titles/links to each entry (as per your mockup).

The query could probably be an asset query using the `relatedTo` param, i.e. something like

```php
/** @var Asset $asset */
$asset = $event->sender;

$relatedEntries = \craft\elements\Entry::find()
    ->relatedTo(['targetElement' => $asset->id])
    ->all();

...
```

...although for performance reasons, you might want to avoid that approach and look into doing a completely custom query.

Here's a complete, albeit simplified (and untested) example of how the solution described above could look (this code would go into your module or plugin's `init()` method):

```php
// Add a custom "Entries" column to asset indexes
Event::on(
    Asset::class,
    Element::EVENT_REGISTER_TABLE_ATTRIBUTES,
    static function (RegisterElementTableAttributesEvent $event) {
        $event->tableAttributes['_relatedEntries'] = [
            'label' => 'Entries',
        ];
    }
); 

// Render a list of edit page links for all related entries, for the custom column
Event::on(
    Asset::class, 
    Asset::EVENT_SET_TABLE_ATTRIBUTE_HTML, 
    static function (SetElementTableAttributeHtmlEvent $event) {
        if ($event->attribute === '_relatedEntries') {
            /** @var Asset $asset */
            $asset = $event->sender;

            // Get all entries related to this asset
            $relatedEntries = Entry::find()
                ->relatedTo(['targetElement' => $asset->id])
                ->all();

            // Build an array of links to the related entries' edit pages
            $entryLinks = [];
            foreach ($entries as $entry) {
                $entryLinks[] = '<a href="' . $entry->getCpEditUrl() . '"'>' . $entry->title . '</a>';
            }

            $event->html = implode(', ', $entryLinks);
        }
    }
);
```

As a good place to start, I'd also recommend looking at the [Asset Usage plugin](https://github.com/born05/craft-assetusage), which does *almost* exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you.
But the problem is, that the asset usage plugin doesn't show, on which entry / entries the asset is inserted. I only see how often it is used.

Comment: I'm aware, which is why I wrote that the Asset Usage plugin does _almost_ exactly what you want, and that you'll need to implement this as a custom module or plugin. I've added a more complete example to the answer now though – hopefully it'll be useful to you :)